# Why using smaller portions are better for extractions

Tags: organic-chemistry, extraction

Why is using one smaller portion more efficient than using one large portion for extraction. No math answer please thank you

Comment: When you say 'portion', are you referring to the amount of just the sample, or of both the sample and the extraction solvent? For example, are you asking about the difference between $10\ \mathrm{mL}$ sample extracted with $100\ \mathrm{mL}$ solvent, versus $100\ \mathrm{mL}$ sample extracted with $100\ \mathrm{mL}$ solvent?  Or, the difference between $10\ \mathrm{mL}$ sample extracted with $10\ \mathrm{mL}$ solvent, versus $100\ \mathrm{mL}$ sample and $100\ \mathrm{mL}$ solvent?

Comment: It is not. Using ONE large portion (of solvent I assume) will give you more product than using ONE smaller portion. Unless you have a different definition of efficiency (which is fine but you will need to use maths to explain this I'm afraid)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have 1 liter of water solution of something you want to extract, 1 liter of solvent, and a partition coefficient of 1 (not very practical, but this is just to make the math simpler). You mix them all together, the compound distributes between water and solvent at 1:1 ratio, then you separate the solvent and end up with 50% of your compound. Can we do better than that?

OK, now let's divide the solvent in two equal portions. The first portion of 500 ml takes $1\over3$ of our compound, then the second portion takes $1\over3$ of the rest, or $2\over9$ of the original amount, thus making the total of ${5\over9}\approx55\%$, which is somewhat better than $50\%$.

Believe it or check it yourself, splitting the solvent into more portions will get us even more of our compound. You may call 5% a marginal gain, but with more favorable partition coefficients, the figures may grow quite a while.

And finally, if we split the original solution as well, and apply the portions in the right order, we may get pretty close to the [industrial process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid%E2%80%93liquid_extraction#Multistage_countercurrent_continuous_processes).

Comment: without showing math how will it be more efficient. What is the process

Comment: Showing efficiency without math is pretty much like walking without legs, or talking without tongue. As for the process, imagine two liquids flowing in opposite directions, all the while being in contact with each other and exchanging the substance; now approximate that with finite partitions the best you can.

Answer (score 0):

Because extraction is about maximizing surface area contact between the two solutions, and you simply get more surface area contact with smaller volumes. You can mix two smaller portions faster and more thoroughly than with large portions.